Update table rows sequentially in MySQL
I have the following table that is created by this code
CREATE TABLE enrollments 
(
    person_id INT,
    date DATE,
    duration int
);

INSERT INTO enrollments (person_id, date, duration)
VALUES (1, '2004-01-01', 35),
       (1, '2004-01-15', 60),
       (1, '2004-02-01', 15),
       (1, '2004-09-01', 30),
       (2, '1994-01-18', 30),
       (2, '1994-03-01', 30);

The table looks like:
person_id   date       duration
--------------------------------
    1       2004-01-01    35
    1       2004-01-15    60
    1       2004-02-01    15
    1       2004-09-01    30
    2       1994-01-18    30
    2       1994-03-01    30

I'd like to apply the following logic:
Person 1:
Row 1: 2004-01-01, 35 (no previous row to compare with)
Row 2: 2004-01-15, 60
Previous date + previous duration: 2004-01-01 + 35 days = 2004-02-05. Compare this date with the next row's date:
Since 2004-02-05 > 2004-01-15, update 2004-01-15 to 2004-02-05
Row 3: 2004-02-01, 15
Previous date + previous duration: 2004-02-05 + 60 days = 2004-04-05
Since 2004-04-05 > 2004-02-01, update 2004-02-01 to 2004-04-05
Row 4: 2004-09-01, 30
Previous date + previous duration: 2004-04-05 + 15 days = 2004-04-20
Since 2004-04-20 < 2004-09-01, no change
I have no idea if this is possible and if it is where to start from. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Which RDBMS?  Which version?

@freefaller mysql, 8.4.0.

Why is it tagged mysql-8.3 if it's actually mysql-8.4?

I think you should be able to do what you want using the LAG() window function to get the date and duration from the previous row. Use DATE_ADD() to add the duration.

Then use GREATER() function to use either the existing date or the incremented date from the previous row.

@Barmar I have used the functions you have mentioned but I couldn't get it to work because they operate on the 'date' before it gets updated.

Specify primary key or at least unique constraint in the table (take into account - this unique constraint must provide the uniqueness during the update, after each separate updated row!). W/o it the task cannot be solved.

The algorithm is iterative, so you need in recursive CTE.
If I understand the task correctly, then
CREATE TABLE enrollments 
(
    person_id INT,
    `date` DATE,
    duration int
  , id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY  -- must exist !
);

INSERT INTO enrollments (person_id, `date`, duration)
VALUES (1, '2004-01-01', 35),
       (1, '2004-01-15', 60),
       (1, '2004-02-01', 15),
       (1, '2004-09-01', 30),
       (2, '1994-01-18', 30),
       (2, '1994-03-01', 30);

SELECT * FROM enrollments;




person_id
date
duration
id




1
2004-01-01
35
1


1
2004-01-15
60
2


1
2004-02-01
15
3


1
2004-09-01
30
4


2
1994-01-18
30
5


2
1994-03-01
30
6



WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS (
  SELECT person_id, `date`, duration, id, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY `date`) rn
  FROM enrollments
  ),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT person_id, `date`, duration, id, rn
  FROM cte1 
  WHERE rn = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cte1.person_id, 
         GREATEST(cte1.`date`,
                  cte2.`date` + INTERVAL cte2.duration DAY), 
         cte1.duration, cte1.id, cte1.rn
  FROM cte2
  JOIN cte1 USING (person_id)
  WHERE cte2.rn = cte1.rn - 1
  )
UPDATE enrollments
  JOIN cte2 USING (id)
SET enrollments.`date` = cte2.`date`;

SELECT * FROM enrollments;




person_id
date
duration
id




1
2004-01-01
35
1


1
2004-02-05
60
2


1
2004-04-05
15
3


1
2004-09-01
30
4


2
1994-01-18
30
5


2
1994-03-01
30
6



fiddle
